# How to use participle phrase.

Tags: participles

Here are sentences that I want to trasform using participle phrases.

> 1. Rain was pouring down. We were standing next to each other at a bar and seeing rain droping through the window without saying anything, because we ran out of things to talk about.
> 2. Rain pouring, standing next to each other at a bar, we were seeing rain dropping without saying anything, runing out of things to talk about.

Am I right to do this? If so, what's the diffetence in nuance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the second sentence, just doesn't sound nice, which suggests something is funny about semantics or grammar or...  So, if you want participle phrases, consider:

> Rain was pouring down.  Standing next to each other at a bar and watching raindrops through the window, we were silent, having run out of things to talk about.